# I want to add 2 different matrices and then tell which one's the biggest

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying to write a program that generates 2 matrices and then tells which one is the bigger one. But my problem is that I don't know how to add them. The program says that i and j are not declared in output3 function but they are declared in other functions. I think I might have problems with formatting but I'm new so I don't quite know how to correctly write the code. How can I fix this? Thanks.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#define maxM 4
#define maxN 4
#define maxX 4
#define maxY 4
int tabel1[maxM][maxN];
int tabel2[maxX][maxY];
int sum[maxM][maxN];
int n, m, x, y;
void input1(){
n=4;
m=4;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            tabel1[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }
}

void input2(){
    x = 4;
    y = 4;
    for ( int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            tabel2[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }
}
void output1(){
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("%8d", tabel1[i][j]);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        printf("\n");
    }
    }
}
void output2(){
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("%8d", tabel2[i][j]);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        printf("\n");
    }
    }
}
void output3(){
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            sum[i][j] = tabel1[i][j] + tabel2[i][j];
        }
        printf("%8d", sum[i][j]);
    }
}
main(){
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    printf("First:\n");
    input1();
    output1();
    printf("Second:\n");
    input2();
    output2();
    print("Added up:\n");
    output3();
}
```

Comment: `main(){` in `c++` the standard says you can't omit the return type. With that said your code is mostly `c` with a few `c++` headers used.

Comment: First you should remove the global variables and use local variables or pass them to the function.

Comment: This i, j error comming from output3 function. Make int i = 0 and int j = 0

Comment: Does `c` default to `int` when you don't declare a variable? A `c++` compiler should complain and not compile this.

Comment: @drescherjm C99 doesn't default to `int` and C89 doesn't allow declarations in for loops. I think even C89 doesn't default to `int`

Comment: Variables only live within the code block where they are declared. `i` and `j` are not declared within the scope of `output3()`. Besides, determining which matrix is biggest does not make sense without a definition of "biggest".

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're a bit new to C++, because you used a lot of C features. I improved your code so it is more C++-like, and fixed the errors.

```cpp
#include<iostream> //iostream is the c++ equivalent for getting characters from input and putting output.
//#include<cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#define maxM 4 //next time, maybe don't use macros in c++. I would recommend using "const int MaxM = 4;" or something like that.
#define maxN 4
#define maxX 4
#define maxY 4
int tabel1[maxM][maxN];
int tabel2[maxX][maxY];
int sum[maxM][maxN];
int n, m, x, y;

using namespace std; 

void input1() {
    n = 4;
    m = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            tabel1[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }
}

void input2() {
    x = 4;
    y = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            tabel2[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }
}
void output1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout<< tabel1[i][j]; // "<<" means put into cout, and cout is Console OUTput 
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << endl; //or \n
        }
    }
}
void output2() {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout<<tabel2[i][j]; //again, use cout, not printf()
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << endl; //or /n
        }
    }
}
void output3() {
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) { //you forgot to define i and j, remember to put int before them
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            sum[i][j] = tabel1[i][j] + tabel2[i][j];
            temp = j;
        }
        // original code here: cout<<sum[i][j]; j was outside the loop, so it was out of scope
        cout << sum[i][temp]; //this is new code
    }
}
int main() { //you forgot to put int main, and only had main. C++ does not allow this.
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    cout << "First:\n";
    input1();
    output1();
    cout << "Second:\n";
    input2();
    output2();
    cout<<"Added up:\n";
    output3();
    return 0;
}
```

In two of the for loops, you put only `i = 0; ...`, and so the compiler didn't know what type `i` and `j` were. Also, in another loop, you had `sum[i][j]` outside of `j`'s for loop, so the compiler didn't know what j was. I solved this by making a variable `temp`, storing `j`'s value in `temp`, and doing `sum[i][temp]`. Also, in C++, we use `cout` instead of `printf()` (read on iostreams). Finally, in `main()` you forgot to put `int` as the return type for `main()` (this is required in C++).

Also, in C++, I would avoid using macros, and try to do things like `const int`. If you have to use macros, make them all caps at least.

Your code works now!